# Android MediaRecorder record voice only, not output

Tags: android, mediarecorder

Writing an android application which will allow users to play music and record to that music. I've been using media player to play the background track and MediaRecorder to record in a background thread. When recording I get my voice from the mic and the output from the headphones. Is there a way to stop the output stream from being recorded as well? I'm using a 2012 Galaxy Nexus phone to test this.

Answer (score 0):

I was using headphones with try connector which I think was the culprit. I tried with a regular trs connector and I only received the microphone feed.